# Question on atomless sigma algebra

Tags: logic, set-theory, boolean-algebra

Dear mathstack community,

I have been struggling to understand the definition of the atomless $\sigma$ algebra consisting of the collection of periodic subsets of $ω1$. Defined here (in the answer of Joel Hamkins) :

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22477/sigma-algebra-without-atoms

In particular, I had the following questions:

(1) How does complementation work ?

(2) Could you give me a concrete example of how the join of two elements is formed in this algebra?

(3) Could you give me a concrete example of how the meet of two elements is formed in this algebra?

Also if you could simply point out some standard text book where I can read more about this particular example if would be very grateful (The wikipedia entrance I did not find very helpful). Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear whether you're asking about the countable atomless **boolean** algebra (periodic subsets of $\omega$) or about the example of an atomless **$\sigma$-algebra** (periodic subsets of $\omega_1$)

Comment: The second one ! I will modify the question to make it clearer! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) $\neg A=\omega_1\setminus A$. To see that this is a periodic set note that to build a set $A$ in the $\sigma$ algebra you start with a countable ordinal $\alpha$ and some set $a\subseteq \alpha$, and then "translate $a$" until you have a periodic set. Then $\omega_1\setminus A$ is obtained starting with the same $\alpha$, but instead taking $\alpha\setminus a$ as the subset to repeat.

(2) by taking their union.

(3) by taking their intersections.

Unfortunately I don't know a reference discussing this example in particular.

Comment: Thanks! This helps alot already! However, could you maybe give me an example of building a set A ? What exactly does it mean to "translate a"?

Comment: @EddieChau You divide $\omega_1$ into blocks on length $\alpha$ and pick a set like $a$ in every block. So for example the first block is $[0,\alpha)$ and contains $a$. The second block is $[\alpha,\alpha 2)$ and contains $\alpha+b$ for every $b\in a$. There will be a block for every countable ordinal as in the mathoverflow question